# Migrate from Texniccenter to Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, mactex, texniccenter

I want to "migrate" my Texniccenter Output Profile (Win7/64) to Texmaker (Mac). I installed TexMaker and the MacTex-2013 Distribution. Now, as there is no related question yet, (a) how do I duplicate the following output parameters in TexMaker?

- `PDFLatex`
- `Biber`
- Makeindex: (1.) `"%tm.idx" -t "%tm.ilg" -o "%tm.ind" -s personal.ist` and (2.) `"%tm".nlo -s nomencl.ist -o "%tm".nls`

Furthermore, (b) is it possible to connect it to Skim for forward and reverse functionality?
(c) The personal.ist I have backed ip, just don't know where to put it yet.
(d) Is it possible to program it to make enough runs (3?) for a final output?

Comment: For a possible migration: Configuring Texmaker via Open Texmaker->`Options`->`Configure Texmaker`->`Commands` with same command line arguments as in TeXnicenter would be enough. Texmaker has integrated pdf viewer and even external pdf viewers can also be used by switching built-in viewer to External viewer in `Configure Texmaker Commands Window`.

Comment: This should answer the `biber` part: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153359/setting-up-texmaker-on-mac-to-work-with-biber/153379#153379

Answer (score 2):

Texenthusiasts Comment above already answers most of the questions. If you cannot get `Biber` to work with `MacTex` and `Texmaker` try this `rm -fr /var/folders/GT/GTSW-4xWG4e7gPwCb+0Sxk+++TI/-Tmp-/par-usr/cache-fe147f467ff57455‌​‌​f519af2e054cbfc46578602e` in your terminal and try again.

Comment: That is probably not the same name on all mashines