# Setting up TexMaker on Mac to work with biber

Tags: texmaker, biber

I am trying to make TexMaker (Mac) work with biber. I, naively, tried to change the configuration of the TexMaker by replacing bibtex by biber, but of course such a primitive way of solving issues will never work.

This is the configuration line I have for BibLatex in my TexMaker Preferences:

> "/usr/texbin/bibtex" %.blg

Can anybody help?

PS: I can compile and work with TexShop, but I prefer TexMaker.

Comment: If `biber` is in `/usr/texbin/` then I think you want `"/usr/texbin/biber" %.bcf` or just `"/usr/texbin/biber" %`.

Comment: Related [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/15717)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set up `biber` in Texmaker, do the following. Click on `User`, `User Commands`, `Edit User Commands`. You can define five custom commands there. Pick one that is unused (if any) and fill it as shown below.

[image]

Click `Ok`.

The new command will then be featured in the list of available commands.

[image]

Comment: What do I have to do after I configure this new command? Do I press this new command and then press quick build? Thanks. @Jubobs

Comment: @kwy It's been a while since I last used Texmaker, but I think you can either select it and then press the arrow to run just the new "biber" command, or your can go into Texmaker's settings to configure your Quick Build to run "biber".

Comment: I created this new command but i had "Process started

Process exited with error(s)", without stating which error it is.   @Jubobs

Answer (score 1):

`biber` runs on a file with the file ending `.bcf`. In Texmaker `%` is used as a placeholder for the basename of the current file, so you need

```
biber %.bcf
```

if `biber` is in the path, or

/path/to/biber %.bcf

replacing `/path/to/` with the directory where `biber` is located, e.g. `/usr/texbin/biber %.bcf`.

Comment: After this, what should I do?  Do I simply press quick build or a particular sequence of commands? Thanks. @Torbjørn T.

Comment: @kwy The basic sequence is `pdflatex` - `biber` - `pdflatex`. Quick Build can be set up to do various things, included running all of the above, I don't know what you've done.