# Texmaker: Switch forth and back between Bibtex and Biber

Tags: bibtex, texmaker, biber

I have to work on multiple documents, some of which are under my control and I want to use Biblatex with Biber, others which require to use Bibtex.

I use **Texmaker** on Linux. I find it very annoying that there is only one global preferences for the bibliography backend (Options > Configure Texmaker > Bib(la)tex).

Is there a way to **quickly switch between Biber and Bibtex** depending on the document I am editing. That is, without having to edit the preferences all the time?

Comment: You can define user macros.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153359/setting-up-texmaker-on-mac-to-work-with-biber/153379#153379

Comment: You could also use `arara`. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/integration-of-arara-in-texmaker

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @johannes-b. So I can use User > User Commands. If you want to use the Wizard to assemble existing commands, one can abuse a predefined extry such as "Asymptote" (which I have never used) to run actually `biber %`, and leave `Bib(la)tex` for `bibtex %.aux`.

Comment: Be warned in future you or someone may need `Asymptote` and it may create problems,don't configure `asymptote` entry with `biber`. I suggest you use `Biber` as `User Commands` in Texmaker see [Making only biber as user command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154788/15717) and leave `Bib(la)tex` for `bibtex %.aux`