# Run biber in TexMaker, Ubuntu

Tags: texmaker, biber

I am compiling my project with TexMaker 4.1-1 in Ubuntu 14.04. I have TexLive 2013 and Biber 1.8-1.

I have to compile it running first the TexMaker Quick Build with LuaLaTeX + View PDF, then running biber on the terminal, and then running the TexMaker Quick Build again.

I would like to be able to run biber on TexMaker. Following [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153359/setting-up-texmaker-on-mac-to-work-with-biber), I naively set the 1: User Command as biber %.bcf, but it does not work. Anybody knows how I should proceed? Many thanks!

Comment: See also [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the user command should just be `biber %` (as in TeXstudio). Credits to the guys in [Biblatex + Biber + Texmaker + MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/biblatex-biber-texmaker-miktex).

Comment: Absolutely right! I thought I had tried that, but no... Thanks!