# TexLive 2016 with biber and TexMaker --> How to make it run?

Tags: texmaker, biber, texlive-2016

I started writing a book last year with

- "TexLive 2015"
- my literature managed by "biber"
- own biblio files bbx and cbx
- "Texmaker" as editor

and everything worked smoothly.

As my old computer started having some troubles, I bought a new one and installed "TexLive 2016" from scratch on it, copied the biblio files (bbx anx cbx) to the respective folders as where they were before and made any settings in "Texmaker" analoguous to what I had on the old computer.

However when I try to compile my book.tex file, it ends up in error messages saying that my bibio files are not found.

A rearch in the forums revealed that "TechLive 2016" is incompatible with biber 2.6. So I tried removing biber 2.6 and replaced it by biber 2.4, but the errors remain unchanged.

Currently, **I'm totally lost** and afraid, that all the weeks of work on my book is doomed.

Could anyone give me please some information how I can get this software back to work? As I am a newbie, a more detailed description of a remedy is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Oli

**Further information:**

Here the detailed version of what I did:

1. Installation of *Linux Mint 18*, 64 Bit, Mate on a blank harddisk.
2. Download of *texlive2016-20160523.iso* and extraction of that file into a new folder *texlive*.
3. In that folder *texlive* `sudo ./install-tl -gui` and installation of *TexLive 2016*.
4. In terminal environment variable adjusted: `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH`
5. In terminal normal user (Oli) endued with rights: `sudo chown -hR Oli /usr/local/texlive/2016`
6. In terminal *TexLive Manager* started with `tlmgr gui` and complete update of *TexLive* (around 375 packages were updated).
7. Copy of my biblio files `iest_neu.bbx` and `iest_neu.cbx` from my old computer to the two folders where they used to be, which are `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/biblatex-iest` and a hidden folder in my home folder `~/.texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-iest` (ownerships and flags of the copied files were checked for correctness).
8. In the editor *Texmaker* adaption of the preferences analoguously to what they looked like on my old computer, which relates to only three settings: a) the *PdfLaTex* path was set to `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex`, b) the *Bib(la)tex* entry to `biber %`, and c) in the quick compilation settings, the radio button was set to the second position.

When I compile my `book.tex` file on the old computer, it runs through smoothly. The same tex file on the new computer yields many error messages, of which two principles are identified:

1. File: **/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty**, Type: **Error**, Lines: **13001 and 13002**, Message: **! Package biblatex Error: Style 'iest_neu' not found. See the biblatex package docu...**
   [image]
2. File: **/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty**, Type: **Error**, **Many lines...**, Message: **! Package biblatex Error: Command '\cite' undefined. See the biblatex package docu...**
   [image]

As proposed, I tried to locate my biblio files by *kpsewhich*. For that, an additional installation of package `texlive-binaries` was necessary. However when I searched for my biblio files `iest_neu.bbx` and `iest_neu.cbx`, as well as for the file `biblatex-examples.bib`, *kpsewhich* neither gives an output, nor an error message. Nonetheless, when I look for these files in Midnight Commander, I truly find them (my biblio files `iest_neu.bbx` and `iest_neu.cbx` at the places already mentioned above and the file `biblatex-examples.bib` in the folders `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex/examples` and `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/biblatex`).

The attempted removal and reinstallation of `biblatex` in `tlmgr gui` fails. The logfile outputs this:
[image]

**Solution:**

Finally, I found the solution to my problems by myself. For the scenario

*Texlive 2016 + biber 2.6 + TexMaker 4.4.1 + own biblio files (`*.bbx` and `*.cbx`)*

I state that in contrast to *Texlive 2016 + biber 2.4* the following changes need to be done - otherwise your tex files will fail to compile:

- your own biblio files need to be in your home directory in a *visible* folder `~/texmf/tex/latex/` (formerly, it was possible to put them in a hidden folder)
- in the preferences for *Bib(la)tex* in *TexMaker*, you need to indicate the full path like that `"/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/biber" %` (formerly, it was sufficient to write `biber %` there)

Best regards,

Oli

Comment: 1. Don't panic. 2. biber 2.6 is compatible with texlive 2016, reinstall it. 3. It could be that you will have to adapt your own bbx and cbx-files to the newest biblatex version. But as you didn't say what errors you get, didn't show your files and didn't show a minimal example it is not possible to say more.

Comment: Not finding files is usually a different problem than finding the files, but thinking there's a version mis-match. If you are worried about the *finding* problem, try `kpsewhich myfile.bbx` (if looking for `myfile.bbx`); is the file found?  If not, try `kpsewhich biblatex-examples.bib`; is that file found? If `kpsewhich` is finding things, then maybe the editor you are using is involved in the problem. If things aren't being found, then that's the first issue to sort out. Please update your question once you have sorted out whether things are being found or not.

Comment: Where did you put the files?

Comment: Please provide the exact text of error messages rather than an interpretation as it is much less likely we will misunderstand due to miscommunication.

Comment: Please take a look at my addendum above.

Comment: Sounds like something is messed up. I would deinstall `biblatex` with the package manager and reinstall it using the package manager. And place the IEST files in the same directory as the book source.

Comment: Out of interest, are you a member of TUBAF?

Comment: @cfr: I uploaded the respective screenshots (cf. above)

Comment: @Johannes_B: I tried to de/reinstall `biblatex`, but this doesn't work (cf. screenshot of the logfile above). As for TUBAF: When looking for an appropriate biblio style, I found the interesting approach by Frank Sandig [link] (http://ekkehardt.lima-city.de/hp/download/ganzneu/v-biblatex-iest_ul.pdf), who is probably a member of TUBAF.

Comment: Hihi, i attended this talk :-)

Comment: Unless you changed the default, your personal TEXMF tree is not a dot directory but `~/texmf`. If you installed the files into the local TEXMF tree reather than your personal TEXMF tree, then you must run `mktexlsr` to update the filename database. The `chown` command may or may not be what you wanted as it fails to specify a group. *How* did you do step 4?

Comment: Please copy and paste the code rather than providing screenshots, which are much more difficult to read and completely inaccessible to screen readers.

Comment: @cfr: As for step 4: I opened a terminal (normal user, **not** root), typed `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH` and pressed <Enter>. There was no output and the cursor was in a new line at the usual prompt like before.

Comment: @cfr: _Concerning the TEXMF tree:_ As outlined in Step 7, I copied my biblio files to **both** folders (cf. above). The TEXMF folder was not modified by myself into a dot directory, but installed like that by TeXLive. _Concerning chown:_ Ownership **and** group were identical to what worked on my old computer, i.e. both belonging to the normal user, not root or something else. _Concerning `mktexlsr`:_ No remedy.

Comment: @Oli That will not change your PATH correctly even for that terminal session. More generally, any changes you make just at the command line will only persist for so long as you remain in the current shell. The TeX Live installer does not create a TEXMF home directory for users as far as I know and it is *not* a dot directory by default. The files are not found in your local tree because it is searched via the filename database. They are probably not found in your home directory because you have probably not put them in the right place. To find your home use `kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME`.

Comment: Did you install a full TeX Live? In any case, you appear to have two installations of TeX: one installed from upstream and one installed with Ubuntu's package manager. You should remove one or other. (I'd recommend removing Ubuntu's.) TeX Live's package manager, `tlmgr`, does not know anything about a package named `texlive-binaries` but Ubuntu's probably does.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I deinstalled with `tlmgr gui` all `biblatex` related packages, 125 in total and reinstalled them afterwards. However, the errors upon compiling my tex file remain unchanged.

Comment: @cfr: There are no two installations of TexLive. In Ubuntu's _Synaptic_ package manager, there are no Tex related packages installed (yet they are there and _could_ be ticked for installation). My TexLive installation was done by downloading  the iso file and in the terminal by typing `sudo ./install-tl -gui`, as outlined in steps 1 to 3 above.

Comment: Ihaven't read the whole comment track, but you cannot install `iest` witl `tlmgr`. It is not inclued in TL. You have toinstall the style according to the github documentation.

Comment: @Johannes_B: That's even obvious to me that the iest files are not part of the standard TL distribution. So I followed once again the github documentation and made my hidden folder `~/.texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-iest`now visible by renaming `.texmf` into `texmf`. As a consequence, The error messages concerning the not found biblio files have disappeared. However now, another single error message appears now: `Error : could not start the command : biber "book"` (the filename of my tex file is _book.tex_). That's odd, because of installation step 8b (cf. above).

Comment: Moreover, I wonder why my biblio files are well found on my old computer, although they are well located there in the hidden `.texmf` folder.

Comment: `biber` is not in your PATH because you haven't set it correctly. `pdflatex` is found because you have configured it with a full path name.

Comment: @cfr: Interestingly, many other pertinent threads (e.g. [link] (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180354/run-biber-in-texmaker-ubuntu)) advise to refer to _biber_ in _Texmaker_ only by the parametre `biber %` - without any path. Perhaps that this is not valid anymore for _TexLive 2016_? Do you know where _biber_ is lying in the file tree?

Comment: That is sensible advice. However, it assumes you have configured your `PATH` correctly. As far as I can tell, you haven't. This is a basic post-installation step required for pretty much anything to work and is not specific to Biber. Just set your PATH. Otherwise, you'll need to use full paths for every single binary in TeX Live.

Comment: @Admins: You may set this thread to [Solved], please. Thanks.

Comment: @cfr Is it worth to add an answer? If so, please do. If not, i assume we can close?

Comment: @Johannes_B I wouldn't know what to say. What solved it? Moreover, at least one of the issues here is to do with PATH and really off-topic. The other is multiple installations, but that's covered elsewhere. I think we should rather close since it is solved.

Comment: @Johannes_B The user seems to have solved it in a less than good way and the question contains misinformation ... (`~/.texliveYYYY` is hidden, but TEXMFHOME has never been by default that I know of.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been resolved in comments, albeit possibly by means which are far from recommended on the basis of information which is less than accurate ....